# show page first then show the data later when loading complete

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `gridview` in my page and during the page load event,I am pinging about 30 IP addresses and show the results in my gridview.

Is there a way to show my page UI first then when the pinging process finishes? The result displays in the gridview. Currently the page will be blank for 15-20s and results appear in the page.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Try
        pingPc(dt.Rows(i)(0))'ipaddress
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Next
loadInfomation()
```

I tried using threading but it doesn't work.

```
th = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf pingPC)
th.IsBackground = True
th.Start(myipaddress)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
th.Join()
```

new code

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf pingPC))
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf LoadInfomation))
```

Comment: i think you need to add EmptyDataTemplate to your gridview.

Comment: gridview shows nothing when there is no data. i know about this.what i means was. load other controls first while gridview is still retriving the data from the server side. when server side finish processing the datas. then update my gridview.

Comment: Sounds like you need some Ajax...

Comment: One way to use ajax and second is to use async method for gridview

Comment: i look throught the gridview async and it was confusing.
i went to look for system.thread.pool as well. but i donno when will my second thread starts. i edited my code already. please advice